# Magento core function working in remote system displaying error in another system

Tags: magento, templates, tabs, product, catalog

In catalog.xml file of frontend template folder I had blocks defined for tabs to display product tags,additional information etc.in this way:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
<alias>additional</alias>
<title>Additional Information</title>
<block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
<template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Which was working fine in the remote system, but when i installed it in local Magento and tried to make one extra .phtml file for displaying brand image in the tab, then in product details page, the following error is displayed:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Tabs.php on line 60

The above file is a part of the core which I did not modify. I tried replacing all the core files but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

look whether it is using any object that is not created in that file